# Angular 11 Circular Dependency detected for services only

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, circular-dependency

I have two Angular services say `WindowDetailsService` and `SessionHelperService`. Now, in my code for `WindowDetailsService` I have  I need to have the below scenario:

**WindowDetailsService:**

```js
import { SessionHelperService } from '../pkg/session/session-helper.service';

constructor(private sessionHelperService: SessionHelperService) {
}

getCurrentSession() {
    const session = this.sessionHelperService.get(true);
}
```

**SessionHelperService**

```js
import { WindowDetailsService } from '../pkg/session/window-details.service';

constructor(private windowDetailsService: WindowDetailsService) {
}

windowOperations(windowType: String) {
    Switch(windowType) {
        case 'Cordova':
            if (shouldCloseWindow) {
                this.windowDetailsService.setReadyToClose(true);
                if (closeSession) {
                    this.closeUserSession(closeSession)
                        .finally(this.windowDetailsService.closeCurrentWindow);
                } else {
                    this.windowDetailsService.closeAllWindows();
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'Web':
            break;
        case 'Electron':
            break;
    }
}
```

The error that I get is
`Warning: Circular dependency detected: session-helper.service.ts -> window.details.ts -> session-helper.service.ts`

`Warning: Circular dependency detected: window-details.service.ts -> session-helper.service.ts -> window-details.service.ts`

I can not take out the code of Window-details from SessionHelperService as it consists the code not only for Cordova window type but also for Web and Electron.

Now my problem is that I can not take out the code related to WindowDetailsService from SessionHelperService and vice versa. Since this is a big
project and if I make change to this, it will impact whole lot of other dependent files in the project. Please suggest as to what should I do

Comment: might be your serviceA is dependent on serviceB and again serviceB is dependent on serviceA. Such that serviceA.funcA() and service.funcB() and 2nd is calling 1st and 1st is calling 2nd...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Injector service to get the `SessionHelperService` this way:

**WindowDetailsService:**

```js
  import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
  
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class ...

  private sessionHelperService: SessionHelperService

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor(private injector:Injector) {
  }

  getCurrentSession() {
    this.sessionHelperService = injector.get(SessionHelperService));
    const session = this.sessionHelperService.get(true);
  }
```

Comment: I'll try this but even if we use Injector, we'd still have reference to `SessionHelperService` in `WindowDetailsService`. So, the dependency would still remain as circular. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

another way is create for example x service file and import your SessionHelperService and WindowDetailsService in that, in this way all your services do their job without circular dependency error